# Extracting mulitple strings in pdf text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently encountering an issue with extracting text from a PDF using Python 3.34

I am using the below to extract ID1; This works fine after I tried running this.

```
text = pdf.getPage(x).extractText()
IDs = extractWhiteText('ID1:([\d]+?)\D', text)
```

When I want multiple ID's using below; nothing returns.

```
IDs = extractWhiteText('ID1:([\d]+?)\D' | ID2:([\d]+?)\D, text)
```

Please can someone assist me in amending the above code to extract multiple ID's.

It may help if I also include the definitions used;

```
def extractWhiteText(pattern, text):
    IDs = {}
    match = re.search(pattern, text)

    if match:
        IDs = {'cID': int(match.group(1))}

    return IDs
```

Comment: `re.search` returns only first occurence. Use `re.finditer` or `re.findall`. See https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html for more info on `re` module. Code would be something like `ids = [int(m.group(1)) for m in re.finditer(pattern, text)]`.

Comment: Perfect, this works :)